# How to disable html form submit button if the input values are the same

Tags: javascript, html

Please I want a simple form validator that disable html input form in the values are the same in js.

```
<input type="text" value="john">
<input type="text" value="john">
<button>Test</button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick way to have that functionality is to listen for the `submit` event on your `form` that checks if both the `input`s have the same value.

Here's a live demo:

```js
/** select the form and both the inputs, select them once and use them as many as needed */
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form'),
  inp1 = document.getElementById('inp-1'),
  inp2 = document.getElementById('inp-2');

/** 
* listen for "submit" events on the form 
* if the trimmed values of both the inputs is the same then we prevent the form from being submitted
*/
myForm.addEventListener('submit', e => inp1.value.trim() === inp2.value.trim() && e.preventDefault());
```

```html
<!-- your form should have an ID to make it easier for us to select it on the JS part -->
<!-- your form should also have an "action" attribute along with the appropriate "method" attribute -->
<form id="my-form">
  <!-- give each input an ID to make it easier for us to select it on the JS part -->
  <input id="inp-1" type="text" value="john">
  <input id="inp-2" type="text" value="john">
  <!-- the button should be of type "submit" to allow submit events to be catched -->
  <button type="submit">Test</button>
</form>
```

> In the above example the [`String.prototype.trim()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) method was used to remove whitespace from both ends of the `input`s values.

The *canceling* of the form submission is done by calling [`preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) method on the [submit event object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/submit_event) that is passed to the listener function (I called it `e`, we usually call it `e` by the way) when both the values of the `input`s, when trimmed, is the same.

The line `inp1.value.trim() === inp2.value.trim() && e.preventDefault())` will call `preventDefault` method only if both the trimmed values of the input is the same (as we're using the `&& (AND)` operator) and will allow the form to be submitted otherwise (when the fields have different values).